# Ordering of format strings in Python's struct

Tags: python, struct

There seems to be some ordering issues when using format strings in Python.

For example, I am trying to unpack, in order: 3 doubles, 1 float, 2 doubles.
This should be `5*8+4 == 44` bytes in size.

Consider the following code:

```
import struct

A = struct.calcsize("dddfdd")
B = struct.calcsize("dddf")+struct.calcsize("dd")
C = struct.calcsize("dddddf")
```

For me, in Python 3.6.9 on Linux, I get that `A == 48`, meanwhile `B == C == 44` (as I would expect).

This means that something like the following would fail, when `packed_data` is `44` bytes.

```
unpacked_data = struct.unpack('dddfdd',packed_data)
```

I can, instead, resort to:

```
unpacked_data1 = struct.unpack('dddf',packed_data1)
unpacked_data2 = struct.unpack('dd',packed_data2)
```

What gives? Is there a better way to do the unpacking?

Comment: It's because of alignment, use the `=` prefix for the format string. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a byte order with your format string:

```py
# assumes a native byte order, size and alignment.
# This means for alignment purposes, that it will align bytes to multiples of 8 bytes
A = struct.calcsize("dddfdd")

# if you prepend '=' infront of the format string, the order assumes system byte order and no alignment
A = struct.calcsize("=dddfdd") 
# A == 44
```

To check your system byteorder you can also use:

```py
import sys
print(sys.byteorder)
```

As reference look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Comment: I see, thanks. Is it padding it to 8 bytes because I have a 64 bit system?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For more information look at e.g. the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#:~:text=64%2Dbit%20aligned%20is%208,memory%20accesses%20are%20always%20aligned.) entry.